# Add counter field in select result in Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with some field.

```
name, stud_id
ali | 100 
has | 230
mah | 300
```

I want to get some of record and show a row field beside of record.

```
1 | ali | 100 
2 | has | 230
3 | mah | 300
```

How I can do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Select (select count(*) from Table1 A where A.stud_id>=B.stud_id) as RowNo, B.*
    from Table1 as B
    order by A.stud_id
```

MS-ACCESS does not have rownum function, so this might help you.
But your ID need to be sortable and unique.